# Плавная прокрутка Jquery

Tags: jquery, анимация

Есть три кнопки в хэдере и каждая из  них привязана к своему блоку на странице. Как мне поправить скрипт что бы при нажатии на кнопку был переход на нужный блок и он(блок) находился посредине окна?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#header").on("click", "button", function(event) {
    var id = $(this).attr('href'),
      top = $(id).offset().top;
    $('body,html').animate({
      scrollTop: top
    }, 1500);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<header id="header">
  <button href=".header">Home</button>
  <button href="#joinTo">How join to?</button>
  <button href=".form">Contact Us</button>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как насчет вычислять смещение по высоте? И если блок больше размера вьюпорта, не смещать. Что-то вроде этого:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#header").on("click", "button", function(event) {
    let id = $(this).attr('href');
    let top = $(id).offset().top;
    let heightOffset = ($(window).height() - $(id).height()) / 2; // вычислили смещение по высоте
    if (heightOffset < 0) heightOffset = 0; // проверили, что не отрицательное
    let centerTop = top - heightOffset; // отняли смещение
    $('body,html').animate({
      scrollTop: centerTop
    }, 1500);
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 300px;
}
#joinTo,
.form {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<header id="header">
  <button href="#header">Home</button>
  <button href="#joinTo">How join to?</button>
  <button href=".form">Contact Us</button>
</header>
<main>
  <div></div>
  <div id="joinTo"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="form"></div>
  <div></div>
</main>
```